# error when making contribution page - "No Contribution Price Sets have been configured"

Tags: price-sets

I have two contribution price sets. When I try to make a Contribution Page I get an error on the second tab "Amounts". When I check the "Contribution Amounts section enabled" check box I get the error: "No Contribution Price Sets have been configured..." but I know I have two price sets.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select price set or Add amounts under 'Fixed Contribution Options'

Comment: I'll check thanks